# What are some options for keeping track of temporary results and re-use them after restart, in case the program dies while running?

Tags: perl

(Suggestions for improving the title of this question are welcomed.)

I have a perl script that uses web APIs to fetch a user's "liked" posts on various sites (tumblr, reddit, etc.), then download some portion of each post (for example, an image that's linked from the post).

Right now, I have a JSON-encoded file that keeps track of the posts that have already been fetched (for tumblr, it just records the total number of likes, for reddit, it records, the "id" of the last post fetched) so that the script can just pick up with the newly "liked" items the next time it runs. This means that after the program is finished archiving a new batch of links, the new "stopping point" is recorded in the JSON file.

However, if the program croaks for some reason (or is killed with ctrl+c, say), the progress is not recorded (since the progress is only recorded at the end of the "fetching"). So the next time the program runs, it looks in the tracking file and gets the last recorded stopping point (the last time it successfully completed fetching and recorded the progress), and picks up there again, downloading duplicates up to the point where it croaked the last time.

My question is, what's the best (i.e. simplest, most efficient, take your pick--I'm open to options here) way to record progress with each incremental archived item, so that if the program dies for some reason, it always knows exactly where to pick up where it left off? Adapting the current method (literally  `print`-ing to the tracking file at the end of each fetch) to do the same thing after each individual item is definitely not the best solution because it's got to be pretty inefficient.

*Edited for clarity*

Let me make clearer that the file used to track the downloaded posts is not large, and does not grow appreciably with each "fetch" operation. There is only one element for each api (tumblr, etc.) that contains either the total number of likes for the account (in other words, the number that we have already downloaded, so we query the api for the current total, subtract the number in the file, and we know how many new items to fetch), or the ID of the last item fetched (reddit uses this, so we can ask the api for all items "after" the one in the file and only get the new stuff).

My problem is not an ever growing list of fetched posts, rather it is writing to the tracking file every time one single post is downloaded (and there could be thousands of posts downloaded in a single run).

Comment: But is efficiency really much of a concern here? I do not know about the dimensions we are talking here, but do you really track enough people or do they spam enough likes that the file grows too big? I assume the speed is no issue as the fetching and downloading has to take orders of magnitudes more time than writing down progress...

Comment: No, I suppose efficiency isn't really that much of a concern. I guess what I mean is "is there a better way to do it?" Not necessarily more efficient, just more "perlish," as they say.

Comment: "perlish"? According to the Camel book, a Perl script is "correct" if it gets the job done before your boss fires you. And one of Perls fundamental concepts is to make the easy things easy and the hard things possible. So i would not argue that a script gets more perlish if you add unneeded complexity. Then again, there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: I see what you're saying. What I am asking though is whether my idea (to write the tracking file many many times in the course of a program run) is the best way to go about it. I'm not trying to make things more complex (or complicated), rather, I'm asking whether there's a simpler way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I do not oppose your question or anything. And if you find some better solution elsewhere, please share it here. I am curious and it might very well help me or others in future projects as well. I just wanted to oppose the notion that the most perlish solution might be anything but the first one that works smoothly. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas I would consider:

- Write to the file more often or use an interrupt handler to 'safely' handle the interrupt signal. When it's called, allow the script to write to your file so it's as current as possible and elegantly quit.
- Use a better storage mechanic than writing to a flat file. I would consider, depending on the need, using a database to store the ids. I groan when database starts getting in play due to the complexities it adds, however it doesn't have to be. I've used SQLite for queuing but also consider DBD::CSV which just writes to a CSV while allowing SQL syntax (haven't used it myself). In your code you could then check if the id is already in the database and know to skip it. I would imagine that SQLite is also more 'efficient' than reading/writing a flat file and, imo, would be easier to code than having to write code to read a file yourself.

Comment: I clarified the OP some since there seems to be some confusion. The problem is not scaling the tracking process, but rather efficiently keeping track of each post that is captured. As such, your first bullet hits more at a solution than your second.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use a hash, tied to an [NDBM file](http://perldoc.perl.org/NDBM_File.html), to keep track of what is loaded and what isn't.

When you start a new batch of URLs, you delete the NDBM file.

Then, in your code, at the start of the program, you do

```
tie(%visited, 'NDBM_File', 'visitedurls', O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)
```

(don't worry about the O_CREAT, the file will remain intact if it exists unless you pass O_TRUNC as well)

Assuming your main loop looks like this:

```
while ($id=<INFILE>) {
    my $url=id_to_url($id);
    my $results=fetch($url);
    save_results($url, $results);
}
```

you change that to

```
while ($id=<INFILE>) {
    my $url=id_to_url($id);
    my $results;
    if ($visited{$url}) {
        $results=$visited{$url};
    } else {
        $results=fetch($url);
        $visited{$url}=$results;
    }
    save_results($url, $results);
}
```

So whenever you fetch a new URL, you write the results to the NDBM file, and whenever you restart your program, the results that have already been fetched will be in the NDBM file and fetched from there instead of reading the URL.

This assumes `$results` is a scalar, else you won't be able to store/retrieve it in this way. But as you're producing JSON anyway, the "partial json" for each URL will probably be what you want to store.

Comment: See my edit to the OP. I'm not trying to track every url ever downloaded and check new downloads against that database to ensure that I don't get dupes. I'm just trying to keep track of the most recent stopping point, so that subsequent runs "know" where to pick up. This means that I can ask the APIs for the various services only for the new stuff, and not even worry about the stuff I already have.

Comment: Whenever you start a new batch of URLs, just delete the NDBM file. It will be re-created empty by your script, so it will only contain the URLs of the current batch.